# SQL AUTO-INCREMENT en SSMS

Tags: sql-server, phpmyadmin, ssms

He exportado una base de datos de *PhpMyAdmin*. Al abrir el documento que me genera al exportar con *Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio* me muestra las consultas de todas las tablas y datos que hay en la base de datos (hasta aquí bien). Dado que alguna de las instrucciones parecen no ser compatibles entre *PhpMyAdmin* y *SSMS*. He tenido que ir modificándolas y ejecutándolas a mano y la mayoría se han ejecutado bién, pero al tener que indicar los campos `AUTO-INCREMENT` me da error.

Por ejemplo al ejecutar la instrucción:

```
ALTER TABLE  categories 
MODIFY Cat_Id  int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=31;
```

Me da el error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1306
>   Incorrect syntax near 'MODIFY'.

¿Cómo solucionar este error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No lo he probado, pero en SQL server la columna no es autoincrement, es IDENTITY y se usa de la siguiente forma:

```
ID int IDENTITY(1,1)
```

donde entre parentesis figuran `(numero inicial, incremento)`.

No se si te va a dejar hacer un alter table, pero ya de por si, estas usando una instruccion que no corresponde.

Comment: Al final lo que pasaba es que al estar ya las tablas creadas y los datos introducidos no me permitía modificar la columna y añadirle el IDENTITY. lo que he hecho ha sido volver a crear las tablas indicando que se incremente antes de introducir todos los datos. Muchas gracias gbianchi por el aporte :D